# Borrowing/scoping issues when pushing &[u8] to a Vec

Tags: rust

I'd like to achieve something similar to the code below, but without incurring the costs of `String` (UTF-8 validation mainly), trying to use `&[u8]` instead:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut outer: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    {
        for _ in 0..1 {
            let mut inner: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
            inner.push("hello");
            inner.push("world");
            outer.push(inner.join(",").to_string());
        }
    }
}
```

But my `&[u8]`-ified attempt below does not compile (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=20130b6377241f1566a724440522443e)

```
fn main() {
    let mut outer: Vec<&[u8]> = Vec::new();
    {
        for _ in 0..1 {
            let mut inner: Vec<&[u8]> = Vec::new();
            inner.push(b"hello");
            inner.push(b"world");
            outer.push(&inner.join(&b','));
        }
    }
}
```

Rustc complains that:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/lib.rs:8:25
  |
8 |             outer.push(&inner.join(&b'!'));
  |             -----       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |             |           |
  |             |           creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
  |             borrow later used here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

While I do understand why the Rust compiler rejects this code, I do not know how to actually fix this, while keeping the concept intact. I basically want to transfer ownership of the result of `inner.join(&b',')` into the `outer` Vec, More generally, creating temporary `[u8]` for text in a loop using `join()`, that are then to be pushed into a outer Vec, without running into ownership issues.

Background: parsing an enormous quantity (as in hundreds of terabytes) of csv files using the [csv crate](https://crates.io/crates/csv), which has variants working with ByteBuffers and with Strings, the larger having a measurable negative performance impact. In the full code, I loop though some fields of each csv record, sometimes modify the value. The selected fields are added to the "inner" `Vec` and then want to create a csv record again with `join()` to add `Vec` of selected records. To avoid the noise of the full code, including CSV parsing etc, I created this MRP above to depict the kind of problem I am facing.

Disclaimer: Still learning Rust, so your understanding and some didactic feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the purpose of the for-loop in your examples? Also, what particular costs of String are you referring to? Do you mean the heap allocation cost, the UTF8 validation cost, or both?

Comment: The final compiler note says _"consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value"_.  Didn't that solve the problem?

Comment: `inner.join(&b',')` would be a `Vec<_>` here. Who do you imagine will own that if you only store a reference to it?

Comment: [Here's the answer to the other question applied here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6269fcd2b07a3b1382c143afff21983). Like pretzelhammer, I'm not sure what "costs" you are hoping to avoid -- `[u8]::join` returns a `Vec` already, so you are not incurring any additional allocations by moving it -- so if this is not the answer you are looking for, please [edit] your question to contain more detail.

Comment: Just edited my post to add some background + clarify the overhead (= UTF8 validation mainly)